# Good distance metric for clustering frequency variables

Tags: clustering

I have a dataset of customers, with variables refering to ABSOLUTE FREQUENCIES (counts). For example, I have the number of times he makes a purchase in weekend, the number of purchases in laborable days, the number of purchases in the morning, afternoon, evening, night... etc.

I want to create custers using kmeans. Which distance metric would you recommend? Euclidean, Manhatan, Hellinger, Jackkard... some other? And which type of normalization/scale/standarization (mean/std, range...)

Thanks!